# How to avoid nested ifs in C?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, struct, nested

I have this code here in C and I want `expCompare` to have no nested ifs. I would like to ask if there is any other way except this?

```
typedef struct expo Exponent;
struct expo {
    char tag;
    int ex;
    int ey;
    int ez;
};

int expCompare(Exponent alpha, Exponent beta) {
    if (alpha.ex > beta.ex) {
        return 1;
    } else if (alpha.ex == beta.ex) {
        if (alpha.ey > beta.ey) {
            return 1;
        } else if (alpha.ey == beta.ey) {
            if (alpha.ez > beta.ez) {
                return 1;
            } else if (alpha.ez == beta.ez){
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about using logical operator `if ( (alpha.ex == beta.ex) && (alpha.ey > beta.ey) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of your example, it is absolutely not necessary to use any `else`, since after a `return`, the program flow cannot continue anyway.

I would have written the comparison function that way:

```
int expCompare(Exponent alpha, Exponent beta) {
    if (alpha.ex > beta.ex)
        return 1;
    if (alpha.ex != beta.ex)
        return -1;
    if (alpha.ey > beta.ey)
        return 1;
    if (alpha.ey != beta.ey)
        return -1;
    if (alpha.ez > beta.ez)
        return 1;
    if (alpha.ez == beta.ez)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Even without early `return`, it is possible to avoid all the indentation by having a succession of `else if` like in:

```
int expCompare(Exponent alpha, Exponent beta) {
    int result = -1;
    if (alpha.ex > beta.ex)
        result = 1;
    else if (alpha.ex != beta.ex)
        result = -1;
    else if (alpha.ey > beta.ey)
        result = 1;
    else if (alpha.ey != beta.ey)
        result = -1;
    else if (alpha.ez > beta.ez)
        result = 1;
    else if (alpha.ez == beta.ez)
        result = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Note that for the particular usage of comparing `struct` objects one field after the other, I wrote a macro used in our code base that simplifies significantly that common pattern. It would go like that:

```
static int compareValues(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

#define COMPARE_VALUES_RETURN_IF_DIFFERENT(a,b) \
    do { int result = compareValues((a), (b)); \
    if(result) return result; } while(0)

int expCompare(Exponent alpha, Exponent beta) {
    COMPARE_VALUES_RETURN_IF_DIFFERENT(alpha.ex, beta.ex);
    COMPARE_VALUES_RETURN_IF_DIFFERENT(alpha.ey, beta.ey);
    COMPARE_VALUES_RETURN_IF_DIFFERENT(alpha.ez, beta.ez);
    return 0;
}
```

In our case, `compareValues` is a overridden function in C++ that can compare several types, not only `int`, but you get the point.